Schur Weyl Duality for Maximal Torus
I wanted to know if there's some version of Schur Weyl Duality for the maximal torus $T \subset \operatorname{GL}(V)$? Is there also some combinatorial object which might be useful for the same?

What sort of duality would you have in mind?  The only obvious candidate is what Wikipedia calls the "theorem of the highest weight", but that's not really a duality.

@LSpice I want to decompose $(C^d)^{\otimes k}$ into irreps of the canonical representation of $T$, and I want to understand the multiplicities of each.

As @LSpice has basically said, isn't this what the entire theory of weights (which is at the heart of the representation theory of semisimple Lie groups) is about?

I think I have some grasp on the multiplicities, but I want to know if it is known about the commutant of the algebra generated by $T^{\otimes n}$ as some generalisation of the permutation tensor algebra which is the commutant of $GL(V)^{\otimes n}$
